# How to update Jtable propertly using a class extending AbstractTableModel?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

This `class extends AbstractTableModel`. It has an ArrayList arr but I don't know how to use the fire methods.

```
 public void adiciona(Entidad e) {
    if(DEBUG)
            System.out.println( " tamaño: "+tamaño()+" columas: "+getColumnCount()+"" +        Arrays.deepToString(columnNames) ); //size 6

    arr.add(e);//adds
    if(DEBUG)
            System.out.println( " tamaño: "+tamaño()+" columas: "+getColumnCount()+"" +   Arrays.deepToString(columnNames) ); //size 7

    //setNumRows( getRowCount() - 1 );
    //System.out.println( "hola");

    fireTableStructureChanged();//BOOOOm EXEPTION NULL POINTER ARRAY
    fireTableDataChanged();
    System.out.println( "hola");
 }
```

i am checking the java source on how java has the default table model ... what would be the equivalent for

```
 private void justifyRows(int from, int to) {
    arr.setSize(getRowCount());

    for (int i = from; i < to; i++) {
        if (dataVector.elementAt(i) == null) {
            dataVector.setElementAt(new Vector(), i);
        }
        ((Vector)dataVector.elementAt(i)).setSize(getColumnCount());
    }
}
```

in an ArrayList

Comment: Yes when you add you have to call fireRowsInserted , this will notify the view, that ssomething in the model has change, and then the view has to update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It has an ArrayList

Then use a custom TableModel that supports an ArrayList containing any custom Object.

For example you could use the [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/). It provides a custom TableModel that stores custom Objects in an ArrayList. You will need to implement the getValueAt() and setValueAt() methods as they related to your custom Object. The  `JButtonTableModel` example shows you how this can be done.

Comment: Thank you very much. Definetly now I also think that for the minor changes I am doing it is not worth to extend and create the AbstractTableModel. I just finished extending the `DefaultTableModel` with some helper methods (and overriding some others) to make the `ArrayList` to Vector changes but i will definetly use the `RowTableModel` next time